# Prove this morphism is a derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ a ring, $B$ a $A$-algebra, $I=\ker (B\otimes_A B \to B)$ given by multiplication, i wanna see why is $$d:B \to I/I^2$$
$$b \mapsto b\otimes 1 -1 \otimes b$$
 well defined (in fact, why mod $I^2$), and an $A$-derivation?
Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $B$ is an $A$-algebra. The map is well defined because... well it just is. Did you try proving additivity? $A$-linearity? the Leibniz rule? Each is straightforward if you just sit down with a piece of paper and write it out.

Comment: Of course, a $A$-algebra. Linearity is clear, but the Leibnitz rule not!! And what i mean by "well-defined" is why in $I/I^2$ and not in $I$. Thx

Comment: OK, so $d(b_1b_2) = b_1b_2 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b_1b2$. Compare with $b_1d(b_2) + b_2d(b_1)$. Now you tell me what is the $B$-module structure on $I/I^2$?

Comment: The $B$-module structure comes from the multiplication on the right factor on $B\otimes_A B :\ b.(b_1\otimes b_2)=b_1\otimes bb_2$.

Comment: I have $bd(b')+d(b)b'=b'\otimes b-1\otimes bb'+b\otimes b'- 1 \otimes bb'$

Comment: OK, so write out the value for $b_1d(b_2) - b_2d(b_1)$ and substract from $d(b_1b_2)$. What do you get?

Comment: $ b_1b_2\otimes 1-1\otimes b_1b_2+b_2\otimes b_1-b_1\otimes b_2 $

Comment: OK. Is this in $I^2$?

Comment: Oh my god... Really sorry! Thank you, i think i'm good for stop math for tonight!!

Comment: You may have a sign error somewhere.

Comment: Cause u said $b_1d(b_2)-b_2d(b_1)$! It's a plus, then take the difference

Comment: OK, anyway, I think you got it now. Good night!

Comment: Anyway, i'm in I^2. Just didn't think...